# How to solve below error in Python programming language

Tags: python

I wrote a code for resume for parser, and sadly for one particular resume there is always error, list index out of range but for rest of the resumes it's working, irrespective of the number of the resumes present in the folder.

```
doc = nlp(text)
name = [entity.text for entity in doc.ents if entity.label_ == 'PERSON'] [0]
print(name)
email = [word for word in doc if word.like_email == True][0]
print(email)
```

Error:

```
    email = [word for word in doc if word.like_email == True][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: That index would only be out of range if this list is empty, so _none_ of the `word in doc` was `like_email`.

Comment: Before you try to get the `[0]` element, you should check that the result of your list comprehension has any elements, which as the error is saying you don't

Comment: Are you using spacy to parse resumes?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Talha Tayyab: yes, iam using spacy

Answer (score 1):

It would seem that none of the words in `doc` met your criteria.

You can write this using `next` and a generator expression. Doing so does not force you to create an entire list just to find the first matching element.

```
email = next((word for word in doc if word.like_email), None)
```

This returns `None` if nothing was found. The second argument can be whatever default value you want, though.

Comment: Done, as you said , but it is showing this error now   "raise ValueError("All arrays must be of the same length")
ValueError: All arrays must be of the same length"

Comment: That is likely being raised by `word.like_email`.